# Delete Hook, deletes all the entries in the database automatically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I created a delete hook to individually delete some data on a screen but every-time I load the hook, it deletes all the entries on the page. I am trying to be able to click an icon and delete an item. I am passing the id of the item through the props, then calling my delete function but instead of waiting for user input the hook deletes everything in the database. Any help is appreciated.

**Hook**

```
import { useContext } from 'react';
import { Context as CertificationContext } from '../context/CertificationContext';
import { Context as CertificateInfoContext } from '../context/CertificateInfoContext';

export default () => {
  const { deleteCertification } = useContext(CertificationContext);
  const {
    state: { certificationId }
  } = useContext(CertificateInfoContext);
  console.log('Delete' + certificationId);
  const removeCertification = async id => {
    await deleteCertification(id);
  };

  return removeCertification;
};
```

**Component**

```
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { Button } from 'react-native-elements';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Feather';
import { navigate } from '../navigationRef';
import useDeleteCertification from '../hooks/useDeleteCertification';

const Certifications = ({ title, month, description, id }) => {
  const removeCertification = useDeleteCertification();
  return (
    <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
      <View style={styles.firstContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.monthText}>{month}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.dayText}>FRI</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.secondContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.subtitle}>{description}</Text>
        <View style={styles.buttonView}>
          <Button
            icon={<Icon name='trash-2' color='grey' size={15} />}
            type='clear'
            onPress={removeCertification(id)}
          />
          <Button
            icon={<Icon name='share' color='grey' size={15} />}
            type='clear'
            onPress={() => {
              console.log('Share Button');
            }}
          />
          <Button
            icon={<Icon name='edit' color='grey' size={15} />}
            type='clear'
            onPress={() => {
              navigate('EditCertification', { id });
            }}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an arrow function in your `onPress` prop like this:

```
<Button
  icon={<Icon name='trash-2' color='grey' size={15} />}
  type='clear'
  onPress={() => removeCertification(id)}
/>
```

Now you are passing a function rather than the result of a function, so it won't trigger on render

Comment: Hi Al, thank you for your answer. I've already tried this and it still deletes everything. That was my initial thought. it seems like ```const removeCertification = useDeleteCertification();``` is running once the screen is rendered.

Comment: Hi Al, so I was able to fix it using your change as well. I was return removeCertification wrong. It should have been returned like ```[removeCertification]``` and called as an array as well. Once I made that change and edited the onPress function as you suggested, it worked fine. Thank you for your help.